# Don't clear console when running file

Tags: pycharm

It's a simple question but I can't find an answer anywhere nor in the settings.

When you execute a file, the console clears. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: An answer has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51466944/3337089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't find it cause it's not there - there is [an open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15661) though, which did not get any attention apparently.