# PyCharm, stop the console from clearing every time you run the program

Tags: python, console, pycharm, settings

So I have just switched over from Spyder to PyCharm. In Spyder, each time you run the program, the console just gets added to, not cleared. This was very useful because I could look through the console to see how my changes to the code were changing the outputs of the program (obviously the console had a maximum length so stuff would get cleared eventually)

However in PyCharm each time I run the program the console is cleared. Surely there must be a way to change this, but I can't find the setting. Thanks.

Comment: did you fix your problem?

Comment: @BrunoGL Scientific mode is only available in the Pro version of PyCharm and I'm using the Community version, but I quickly got used to the console clearing every time and have so far not actually needed any information that had been cleared.I have noticed however that the console does not clear if you run a section of lines of code instead of the whole program. Are there any downsides to running a selection of lines such that the selection is actually the whole program? If not I might do that.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that, my bad.
If to run your final program you need to run only parts of it, then you might need a restructure. If you are just experimenting with things, then it should be fine.
However, if you like running only parts of it at a time, you might consider Jupyter Notebooks. Or if you want to run parts of it but run the whole code every time, you can develop your python scricts but only make the call in a `if __name__ == "__main__:"` statement. It is actually nice for testing only parts of your program at a time.

Comment: @BrunoGL Thanks that's loads on options. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Also, if I ran PyCharm with the iPython interpreter instead of the standard Python interpreter, would the console clear every time? (actually I don't even know if iPython is an interpreter so maybe I can't do that)

Answer (score 2):

In Spyder the output is there because you are running iPython.

In PyCharm you can get the same by pressing on `View -> Scientific Mode`.
Then every time you run you see a the new output and the history there.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm v2018.2.4. There is no `Scientific Mode` option available under `View`. Any idea?